# Run MassTransit/RabbitMQ instance in memory

Tags: .net, unit-testing, rabbitmq, automated-tests, masstransit

I want to implement integration tests. And I would like to not up RabbitMQ instance for it and the only change I want is to modify connection settings in tests (to use memory instance).
Is it possible ?

Comment: please add more information as to what exactly you want to test? is it only sending? or both? do you consider sending and receiving as one test? do you expect to receive what you sent if you separate the test functionality?

Comment: Run RMQ in a Docker container and it will all work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no in-memory instance of RabbitMQ. You could, as pointed out in the comments above, stand up RabbitMQ in a container to run the tests. This is what MassTransit does using [GitHub Actions](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/develop/.github/workflows/build.yml#L135).

MassTransit also has an extensive in-memory transport which can be used for unit tests. The gRPC transport is also designed to be match the RabbitMQ topology, including fanout, direct, and topic exchanges, and can be used without any dependencies.